# Trouble making span classes visible using CSS and jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

How can i target the span tag that is selected to display the values when the page loads? I want to show one list when the page loads. when the user presses the icon the other span list loads.I can either hide it or show both, Is there a way using the display - visible to do what i need?

Having trouble figuring out a solution

```css
.box{
        padding: 20px;
/*         display: none;  
  iv turned this off to show both span classes*/
}


input {
display:none;
}

label input[type="radio"]:checked + img{
    border:1px solid red;
    display:invisible;
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
        if($(this).attr("value")=="red"){
            $(".box").not(".red").hide();
            $(".red").show();
        }
        if($(this).attr("value")=="green"){
            $(".box").not(".green").hide();
            $(".green").show();
        }
    });
});
</script>


 <div id="listitems">
 
        <label><input type="radio" name="colorRadio" value="red" checked="checked" /> <img src="us_flag.png"></label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="colorRadio" value="green"> <img src="eu-flag.gif"></label>

  
<li>Sugar:<span class="red box">4g </span> <span class="green box">1oz</span> </li>
<li>Fiber:<span class="red box">24g </span>  <span class="green box">24oz</span> </li>
   
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find which checkbox is checked before the click function and after the document ready function. I've updated the fiddle and now only the red checked box is shown.

```css
.box{
        padding: 20px;
/*         display: none;  
  iv turned this off to show both span classes*/
}


input {
display:none;
}

label input[type="radio"]:checked + img{
    border:1px solid red;
    display:invisible;
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var checkedValue = $(":checked").prop("value");
    if (checkedValue === "red") {
        $(".red").show();
        $(".green").hide();
    }
    else {
        $(".green").show();
        $(".red").hide();
    }
    $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
        if($(this).attr("value")=="red"){
            $(".box").not(".red").hide();
            $(".red").show();
        }
        if($(this).attr("value")=="green"){
            $(".box").not(".green").hide();
            $(".green").show();
        }
    });
});
</script>


 <div id="listitems">
 
        <label><input type="radio" name="colorRadio" value="red" checked="checked" /> <img src="us_flag.png"></label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="colorRadio" value="green"> <img src="eu-flag.gif"></label>

  
<li>Sugar:<span class="red box">4g </span> <span class="green box">1oz</span> </li>
<li>Fiber:<span class="red box">24g </span>  <span class="green box">24oz</span> </li>
   
 </div>
```

Was this what you were looking for?

Comment: Oh wow. Thanks for the fast response. That is exactly what I am looking for.   I really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the radio buttons' "red" and "green" values match their corresponding spans' classes, makes this very simple. You don't need separate branches for "red" and "green".

```
$('input[name="colorRadio"]').on('click', function () {
    var value = $(this).val();
    var these = $("#listitems span." + value).show();
    $("#listitems span.box").not(these).hide();
}).filter(":checked").click();
```

For good measure, `.filter(":checked").click()` ensures that the initial conditions are correct, on page load.

http://jsfiddle.net/bvbcqL66/

Or if you prefer, a one-liner :

```
$('input[name="colorRadio"]').on('click', function () {
    $("#listitems span." + $(this).val()).show().siblings().hide();
}).filter(":checked").click();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bvbcqL66/1/